# how to dynamically display div at specified location

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, dynamic

i have some html textBoxes on my webpage, now i want to validate the textBoxes using javascript, that means if the textBox does not contain valid data, instead of a classic alert popup i want to display a div beside the textBox which contain the invalid data, can anyone tell me how can i get the textBox position and display the div with the error message beside that textBox....

i am using ajax jquery for that page so do not need any server side code.. and no postbacks.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add that div as an empty div next to that textbox, assign an ID and check, if there are errors change the content of the div

```
document.getElementById('divforTextBox').innerHTML = 'this filed is wrong!';
```

Comment: great, but my issue is i have lots of textBoxes on that page, so i want to avoid using multiple div's and use single div for all textBoxes... and also if i do the above, i need to enable/disable div in case there are multiple invalid entries in textBoxes.. i mean if there are multiple textBox which contain invalid entries i need to handle separate div's for all..

Comment: yes you can, but you have to get the position of every textbox and append the error div on absolute position relative to that textbox. So why don't make it simpler and add thos empty divs, you will also make sure that textboxes will be rendered ok on all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has numerous [validation plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/search/node/valid%20type%3Aproject_project) which can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Check this example.

[Plugins/Validation/Methods/number](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/number)

[Validation plugins in JQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by the following code:

JQuery/JS Code:

```
function validation()
{
    if ($("#username").text() == "") 
    {
       $(".form-field").add("span").text("This is the error message or custom text");
       return false;
    }
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="form-field">
   <input id="username" name="user" type="text" />
</div>

<input type="submit" onclick="validate" />
```